# What is the easiest way to authenticate and manage user in springboot angular8 webapp?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, authentication, jwt

i am doing a website frontend angular 8, backend springboot, maven, hibernate, and mysql db. I am very principiant in authenticate and manage login, users and roles in front end for pages and backend i saw it jwt toutorial or oauth2 but i have not found any toutorial that worked for me. I really appreciate if someone can suggest me a easiest way or link me some tutorial. If you can help me i could need some explanation about what i need in front end with angular and backend with springboot.

Thanks for helps

update...

mt jwt code is the same of this guide

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world

but i can't understand what i need inside JwtUserDetail cause is not present in there... some one knows what i need there?

Comment: Add your implementation here and make clear about your trouble

Answer (score 1):

JWT is a great option. Instead of trying to start from scratch, i think the easiest way is to try [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech). It's a code generation tool that you can download, and use to generate a starter project, with the stack you require (Angular frontend, Spring Boot backend), and JWT authentication. It has an interactive command line UI, that prompts for a lot of options available to generate the app. It also allows to generate code (backend and frontend) for other authentication mechanisms, as you can see here: [Security](https://www.jhipster.tech/security/)

Comment: unfortunatly i have a project started, i can't do it, but you suggest jwt?

Comment: I think it could be a good idea to run JHipster, generate a sample project, and copy the code related with security to your actual project (I did that), or use it to understand how to implement your own solution.

Yes, I recommend using JWT, it's quite simple and stateless, the token contains all the information required to authenticate and authorize a request. So in the future if you need to split the backend into multiple applications, most of them could just examine the token and secure the API access, without querying the users database.